# CONCAT and how to write syntax mysql

Tags: concatenation

I need to create a table for usernames. I need to get my info from a table person. I have to use the concat function to do this.
Im having trouble with the syntax needed.I tried
INSERT INTO users (volunteer_id, username) select concat ('Ronald', 'McDonald');
and many others. HELP am i even close.

Comment: Are you trying to extract two fields from a table named [person]? And then concatenate those two fields together to make a username? Your question needs a lot more detail to get the help you need. Have you checked this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_concat

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :
Insert into users(volunteer_id, username) values(volunteeridvalue, (select concat('ronald','mcdonald'));
Volunteeridvalue being whatever you are inserting in there for that

Answer (score 0):

**create**

```
create table if not exists users (
volunteer_id tinyint(3) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
username char(30)
)
```

**insert all rows**

```
insert into users (username) select concat (first_name,' ', last_name) from person
```

**insert rows with exact value**

```
insert into users (username) select concat (first_name,' ', last_name) from 
person where first_name = 'Ronald'
```

**person** - existing table source of values to insert
**first_name, last_name** - columns in table person
**users** - new table to which values will be inserted
(if they have other names change it in query)